# How can CLAWS move mail from iMap server to local mail folders?

Tags: claws-mail

Since Thunderbird's new developers mangled GPG encryption I've been using "Interlink" as a functional spin off. Unfortunately Interlink is no longer supported and I'm considering "Claws" on Linux.

My standard practice has been to **move** email off the iMap server to targeted local folders as a function of filters. (*I know, I'm using iMap like Pop, but reasons*)

I don't see a way to setup local mail folders under "Claws"?

I saw this question already posted but it was 10 years old with no answers.